# Javascript: Why would one use indexOf() to match a value in a string?

Tags: javascript, indexof

Learning javascript and came across something like this:

```
if (obj.indexOf("someValue") > -1) {
    do.something();
}
```

Without posting the whole script, the indexOf() method was only being used to check for a value in a string.

My question is why you would do that instead of:

```
if (obj.match(/someValue/g)) {
    do.something();
}
```

Is this for legacy browser support or is it faster for some reason?

Comment: Because regex is slow.

Comment: Performance might be the answer: http://jsperf.com/regexp-test-search-vs-indexof/12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is that RegExp `match()` is indeed slower than `indexOf`

You can check [here](http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-indexof).

From the above site only the code:

```
<script>
  var str = "hello world!";
</script>
```

> 5,616,069 Ops/sec  Using **match** time taken is ±3.05% 55% **slower**
>
> 12,306,269 Ops/sec Using  **indexOf()** time taken is ±2.51% **fastest**

Answer (score 1):

`match()` uses regex, regex is slower than `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking it is really more a question of taste. Some could argue though that indexOf is slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `indexOf()` is a simple string search, while `obj.match()` is regExp search. It's just two different things.

When I need to check if is it rainig right now, I just look out the window instead of turning on TV and looking for weather forecast.

P.S.: Btw your "`/g`" makes global search, when `indexOf()` returns only the first occurrence. So in your case `indexOf()` becomes faster (compairing to `obj.match()`) as input string becomes longer.